# MySQL hangs up after binlog rotation

Tags: mysql, centos, log-files, binary

Been having a strange problem lately and wondered if anyone had any input. I'm running a mysql replication setup, with 1 master and 3 slaves. **Every 3 hours or so the binlog on the master fills up and rotates out into a new one. When this happens the master server hangs, and all the connections fill up.**

To get it going I've been restarting MySQL. **During the problem, disk access goes to almost 0 (just some reads of ~100 blocks according to vmstat) and I have over a gig of free RAM. MySQL is consuming minimal CPU (~20%) and the load average is close to** 0. No swapping, etc..

It's like MySQL just gives up trying to accomplish any queries and as a result the connection queue fills up.

MySQL 5.1.47 CentOS 5.5

Like I said, **this problem corresponds in time exactly when the master server rotates the binlog**, I have expire_log_days set to 7, so it's deleting log files too and it seems specific to this deletion rather than creation of a new logfile. **If I perform a manual FLUSH LOGS the server has no problem.**

Would appreciate anyone's input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=44693